# How to get right join with a condition?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

```
appointment
citizen_id | date       | pregnant_consult
         1 | 2021-10-01 |                1
         2 | 2021-10-01 |                1
         3 | 2021-10-01 |                1
         4 | 2021-10-01 |                0
         5 | 2021-10-01 |                0

citizen
id | name   | pregnant
 1 | mary   |        1
 2 | jane   |        0
 3 | linda  |        0
 4 | susy   |        0
 5 | sandra |        1
```

I want to list all appointment with `pregnant_consult = 1` join `citizen`

```
select * from appointment left join citizen on appointment.citizen_id = citizen.id where pregnant_consult = 1
```

this works ok:

```
citizen_id | date       | pregnant_consult | id | name  | pregnant
         1 | 2021-10-01 |                1 |  1 | mary  |        1
         2 | 2021-10-01 |                1 |  2 | jane  |        0
         3 | 2021-10-01 |                1 |  3 | linda |        0
```

but I need to listen the citizen SANDRA because she is `pregnant = 1` like this:

```
citizen_id | date       | pregnant_consult | id | name  | pregnant
         1 | 2021-10-01 |                1 |  1 | mary  |        1
         2 | 2021-10-01 |                1 |  2 | jane  |        0
         3 | 2021-10-01 |                1 |  3 | linda |        0
      null |       null |             null |  5 | sandra|        1
```

Any idea to add "sandra" and not add "suzy"?

Comment: Do you need to use "right join"?

Comment: If I use right join, the citizen "suzy" is appear, but I dont like this because `pregnant = 0`

Comment: @KausUntwale, I do not believe that does anything better considering you are not ruling out the pregnant = 0.

Comment: @Owen you are right, in my head i flipped the left join before adding the or clause. Anyways i deleted my comment so as not to leave incorrect ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no appointment without a citizen, isn't it? Why not swap the tables in the join like this?

```
select * from citizen left join appointment
on appointment.citizen_id = citizen.id 
where pregnant_consult = 1 or pregnant = 1
```

or the same using `right join`:

```
select * from appointment right join citizen 
on appointment.citizen_id = citizen.id 
where pregnant_consult = 1 or pregnant = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to approach. Thus it is hard to answer your question as you did not specify your requirements, limits, etc.

Try this:

```
(select * from appointment a right join citizen c on a.citizen_id = c.id where pregnant_consult = 1) union (select * from appointment a right join citizen c on a.citizen_id = c.id where pregnant = 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution to this question is to use OR operator as below

```
select * from appointment left join citizen on appointment.citizen_id = citizen.id where pregnant_consult = 1 or pregnant = 1
```